# Query's result as json does unexpected result

Tags: sql, sql-server

My current request is

```
SELECT [JSON] = (SELECT [Name] FROM OPENJSON(MyJsonColumn) WITH ([Name] nvarchar(50) '$.Name') for json path) from MyTable
```

the problem is that it fills the JSON column in the result with `[{"Name":"Value"}]` but i'd expect it to be `{"Name":"Value"}` instead. Why is this happening and what could i do to fix the problem?

I've tried to extract `$[0]` from this query's result with `JSON_VALUE` but it returned me `NULL`

Comment: Maybe you need [WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/12/21/without_array_wrapper-new-important-change-in-for-json/), If this is not your solution, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Shnugo thanks, this is what i needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query i was looking for was

```
SELECT [JSON] = (SELECT [Name] FROM OPENJSON(MyJsonColumn) WITH ([Name] nvarchar(50) '$.Name') for json path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) from MyTable
```

Here's more about [WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/12/21/without_array_wrapper-new-important-change-in-for-json/) as Shnugo commented on my question